# How to compare 2 functions in Go?

Tags: function, pointers, go, function-pointers

For example I have list of functions that I want to compare:

http://play.golang.org/p/_rCys6rynf

```
type Action func(foo string)

type Handler struct {
  Get Action
  Post Action
}

var routes map[string]Handler

func Undefined(foo string) {
}

func Defined(foo string) {
}

func init() {
  routes = map[string]Handler{
    `/`: Handler{Defined,Undefined},
  }
}

func main() {
  for _, handler := range routes {
    if handler.Post != Undefined { 
      // do something
    } // invalid operation: (func(string))(handler.Post) != Undefined (func can only be compared to nil)


    if &handler.Post != &Undefined { 
      // do something 
    } // cannot take the address of Undefined
    // invalid operation: &handler.Post != &Undefined (mismatched types *Action and *func(string))
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to compare if two functions are the same?

Comment: The first error message is pretty clear. [Functions are only comparable to `nil`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

Comment: Wouldn't an interface be clearer (and obviously solve the problem) ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Before going further: you should refactor and not compare function value addresses.

[Spec: Comparison operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> Slice, map, and function values are not comparable. However, as a special case, a slice, map, or function value may be compared to the predeclared identifier `nil`.

Function values are not comparable. What you may do is compare if the addresses of the function values are the same (not the address of variables holding function values, but the function values themselves).

[You can't take the address of a function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), but if you print it with the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, it prints its address. So you can use [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) to get the address of a function value.

See this example (based on your code):

```
hand := &Handler{Undefined, Defined}
p1 := fmt.Sprintf("%v", Undefined)
p2 := fmt.Sprintf("%v", hand.Get)
fmt.Println("Expecting true:", p1 == p2)

fmt.Println("Expecting false:", fmt.Sprintf("%v", Defined) == fmt.Sprintf("%v", hand.Get))
fmt.Println("Expecting true:", fmt.Sprintf("%v", Defined) == fmt.Sprintf("%v", hand.Post))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SxhvOZi0Uu)):

```
Expecting true: true
Expecting false: false
Expecting true: true
```

Another option would be to use [`reflect.Value.Pointer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Pointer) to get the address of the function values, this is exactly what the `fmt` package does: `fmt/print.go`:

```
func (p *pp) fmtPointer(value reflect.Value, verb rune) {
    // ...
    case reflect.Chan, reflect.Func, reflect.Map, reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice,
            reflect.UnsafePointer:
        u = value.Pointer()
    // ...
}
```

But you should refactor and not compare function value addresses.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the pitfalls of comparing function addresses?  Also, if the function has an address in memory, why is it not directly addressable? Can you tell me whether in your opinion, the string address value of a function is acceptable [for my use case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42140758/1375316)?

Comment: @threeve Answered in your question: [Collection of Unique Functions in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140758/collection-of-unique-functions-in-go/42147285#42147285)

Answer (score 9):

Nevermind, found the answer:

```
runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(handler.Post).Pointer()).Name() != 
   runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(Undefined).Pointer()).Name()
```

Comment: `reflect.ValueOf(handler.Post).Pointer() != reflect.ValueOf(Undefined).Pointer()` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare function. It need to be stored into a variable instead and reference it as pointer.

http://play.golang.org/p/sflsjjCHN5

Comment: more similar to question https://go.dev/play/p/N_9yq8ZpoCL

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason not to compare functions. If the functions don't have unique identities themselves we don't need to allocate memory for them. Also, the compiler may choose to inline your function making the same function have more than one address or no callable address at all. The spec prohibits function comparison to be able to optimize your code. It's a good thing and you should embrace it.